# Sqlite3 is available in irb, but not in ruby on Mac OS X Lion

Tags: ruby, sqlite, rubygems, osx-lion

I'm trying to start ruby script that uses sqlite3, but I get an error:

```
$ ruby data.rb 
data.rb:1:in `require': no such file to load -- sqlite3 (LoadError)
    from data.rb:1
```

Sqlite3 for ruby is installed

```
$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

sqlite3 (1.3.5)
```

If I try to use sqlite3 from irb it works:

```
$ irb
>> require 'sqlite3'
=> true
```

How can I fix the issue?

Comment: See what happens if you require data.rb from the irb.

Comment: >> require 'data.rb'

=> true

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At the top of your data.rb file try this:

```
require "rubygems"
require "sqlite3"
```

Save and try:

```
ruby data.rb
```

Comment: This is most likely the issue. OS X has Ruby version 1.8.7 and pre 1.9.x versions still need to require rubygems. See http://docs.rubygems.org/read/chapter/3